# Modern ways to perform image processing on a very noisy HVAC LCD display?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am attempting to perform image processing on an HVAC control panel to read status messages. Thus, from the 7 segment display I should be able to extract A76, C90 etc. etc. There is not necessarily a fixed number of characters in the LCD but typically is 3 for a status message. I have partial success in narrowing the larger image down into a region of interest (roi) but fail to identify each 7 segment character from there. I have taken some image pre-processing steps.

[image]

[image: LCD Display normal door open]

I am generally following along with this repository: https://github.com/onlyphantom/cvessentials.

```
`import cv2
import argparse
import re

def thresholding(image):
    return cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", default="assets/a74-min.jpg")
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

# test: dbs.jpg | ocbc.jpg
img_color = cv2.imread(args["path"])
# img_color = cv2.resize(img_color, None, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Needed due to JPG artifacts
temp = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Dilate to better detect contours
temp = cv2.dilate(temp, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3)))


# img = thresholding(img)

# blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7, 7), 0)
# blurred = cv2.bilateralFilter(blurred, 5, sigmaColor=50, sigmaSpace=50)
# edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 130, 150, 255)

t_lower = 255/3  # Lower Threshold
t_upper = 255  # Upper threshold
aperture_size = 7  # Aperture size
L2Gradient = True  # Boolean
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, t_lower, t_upper, apertureSize = aperture_size,
                 L2gradient = L2Gradient)

cv2.imshow("Outline of device", edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# sort contours by area, and get the largest
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:1]

cv2.drawContours(img_color, cnts, 0, (75, 0, 130), 4)
cv2.imshow("Target Contour", img_color)
cv2.waitKey(0)

x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnts[0])
roi = img[y : y + h, x : x + w]
cv2.imshow("ROI", roi)

img_name = re.search("(?<=\/)(.*)(?=\.jpg)", args["path"]).group(1)

cv2.imwrite(f"inter/{img_name}-roi.png", roi)
cv2.waitKey(0)`
```

Any tips or different frameworks to take this image processing further?

Comment: Is the input image supposed to be an image taken by a random person with their phone, or are you installing a camera to look at your control panel? In the latter case, you could square it out a bit better and prevent all the perspective distortions and what not. You could also clean the window in front of it. Anything you can do on the imaging side to make the processing simpler is worth while.

Comment: Solid advice. The end mounting situation is up in the air but should be close to the lcd screen on the inside if we can get enough of a perspective instead of the phone camera shot. I'll try to get it mounted and cleaned and get a body of images to look at.

Comment: If you mount the camera in a fixed position, all you need to do once, manually, is mark a spot on each of the LCD segments. The rest then is trivial: look at the intensity at each spot, and you know which segments are on and off. It should be trivial to use that information to “decode” the message on the screen.

Comment: you might as well attach to the segment display's electronic input and read it out like that, electronically.